# Mybatis xml how to work with concrete implements of abstract class

Tags: java, mybatis

Hello we are using MyBatis to interact with our Postgres cluster in our Java service. We have a table (assume name is `testing`) where we perform select query on our table via xml. The input to our select query is an object whose one attribute could be one of the concrete implementations of an abstract class. How do I figure out in mybatis which concrete implementation of the abstract class this is and based on that add some `WHERE` clauses to my `SELECT` query.

```
public class InputA {
  int a;
  BaseClass b;
}

public abstract class BaseClass b {
  String alpha;
}

public class ConcA extends BaseClass {
  String beta;
}

public class ConcB extends BaseClass {
  String gamma;
}

// Select query - 

Select * from testing
where 
<if test="input.b.type == 'ConcA'"> // Is this supported?
  testing.beta = input.b.beta
</if>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to write `<if test="input.b instanceof xxx.yyy.ConcA">`.